# Groovy @Canonical and @TupleConstructor choking with abstract base class

Tags: groovy, constructor

I have the following Groovy classes:

```
@Canonical
abstract class BaseEntity {
    Long id
    String refId
}

@Canonical
@TupleConstructor(includeSuperFields = true, includeFields = true)
@ToString(includeSuperProperties = true)
class GroceryItem extends BaseEntity {
    String name
    Integer quantity
}
```

Then at runtime I'm creating an instance of `GroceryItem`:

```
GroceryItem cheeseWedges = new GroceryItem(1L,
    '067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00', 'Cheese Wedges', 4)
```

When this constructor runs I get the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.example.myapp.GroceryItem(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1732)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1532)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
```

What's going on here? What's the fix? Is the fact that `BaseEntity` is abstract causing problems here? I seem to remember having a similar issue with these annotations + ABC's a few years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you might aware that `Canonical` itself is combination of `ToString`, `TupleConstructor` and `EqualsAndHashCode`.

- Here since you are explicitly specifying `TupleConsturctor` with options, `Canonical` may be removed for sub-class i.e., `GroceryItem`.
- Apart from it, need to `includeSuperProperties=true` options for `TupleConsturctor` in order to achieve the desired behaviour. Here is [blog](http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2011/04/groovy-goodness-tuple-constructor.html) which you can refer for more details.
- Since the base class is `abstract`, annotation is not required.
- In case if the base class is regular class, and you want to call `super()` of base class constructor, then `callSuper=true` option can be included to `TupleConstructor` annotation of child class. Of course, `Canonical` would be required that time for base class as well.
- In case if a property is defined with access modifier in base class, say `public String description` then `includeSuperFields=true` option needs to be added to `TupleConstructor` of child class.

Here is fixed code snippet:

```
import groovy.transform.*

abstract class BaseEntity {
    Long id
    String refId
}

@TupleConstructor(includeSuperProperties=true)
@ToString(includeSuperProperties=true)
class GroceryItem extends BaseEntity {
    String name
    Integer quantity
}

def item = new GroceryItem(1L,'067e6162-3b6f-4ae2-a171-2470b63dff00', 'Cheese Wedges', 4)
println item.toString()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/aeDaTf)</kbd>